# Example with camera glm / OpenGL immediate mode

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I can't get the camera transforms to work with glm...
Probably just a silly thing I missed but I just can't find it... help?

```
  glViewport(0, 0, m_width, m_height);
  glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  float fovy = 60.0f;
  float aspect = m_width / float(m_height);
  float znear = 0.1f;
  float zfar = 100.0f;
  glm::mat4 Mp = glm::perspective(fovy, aspect, znear, zfar);
  glMultMatrixf(&Mp[0][0]);
  
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  
  glm::vec3 eye = glm::vec3(5, 5, 5);
  glm::vec3 lookat = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
  glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
  glm::mat4 M = glm::lookAt(eye, lookat, up);
  glMultMatrixf(&M[0][0]);

  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
  glVertex3f(-10,-10,-10);
  glVertex3f(10,-10,-10);
  glVertex3f(10, 10,-10);
  
  glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
  glVertex3f(-10,-10,-10);
  glVertex3f(10, 10,-10);
  glVertex3f(-10, 10,-10);
  glEnd();
```

This gives the following output:
m_width = 1024, m_heigth = 768

[image]

Comment: [tag:glm] (generalized linear models) != [tag:glm-math] (GLM - OpenGL Mathematics)

Comment: hmm... maybe I just picked too simple geometry

Comment: The unit of the angle argument of [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00243.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) is [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian): `glm::perspective(glm::radians(fovy), aspect, znear, zfar);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml), the unit of the angle argument of [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00243.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) is [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). Use [`glm::radians`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00373.html#ga6e1db4862c5e25afd553930e2fdd6a68) o convert from degrees to radians:

<s>`glm::perspective(fovy, aspect, znear, zfar);`</s>

```cpp
glm::perspective(glm::radians(fovy), aspect, znear, zfar);
```

Instead of [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) followed by [`glMultMatrixf`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml) you can use [`glLoadMatrixf`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml).
In addition, you can use [`glm::value_ptr`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00305.html#ga1c64669e1ba1160ad9386e43dc57569a) to get a pointer to the matrix fields:

```cpp
float fovy = 60.0f;
float aspect = m_width / float(m_height);
float znear = 0.1f;
float zfar = 100.0f;
glm::mat4 Mp = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fovy), aspect, znear, zfar);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(Mp));

glm::vec3 eye = glm::vec3(5, 5, 5);
glm::vec3 lookat = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
glm::mat4 M = glm::lookAt(eye, lookat, up);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(M));
```